# Проверка на пустоту значения элемента массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Необходимо проверить, есть ли у элемента какое-нибудь значение, то есть не пустой ли он. Иными словами, если он пустой - выполнять if, я делаю так, не работает.

```
if (clients[msg[1]] == "") {
}
```

То есть даже если он пустой - условие не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно определиться с тем, что вы понимаете под "пустыми элементами".

Посмотрите этот код, в зависимости от того, как мы формулируем условие, пустыми могут быть как [falsy-значения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) так и какие-то конкретные значения.

Чтобы точнее понимать происходящее, изучите [сравнение в js](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Получим falsy-значения:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (!arr[i]) {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```

Получим `undefined`/`null`-значения:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] == undefined) {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```

Получим `undefined`-значения:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] === undefined) {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```

Получим `null`-значения:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] === null) {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```

Ищем пустые строки, но снова получим `falsy`-значения (некоторые).
При этом значения `undefined`/`null`/`NaN` уже не попадут в выборку:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] == "") {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```

Получим только пустые строки:

```js
const arr = ['string', 1, undefined, null, 0, '', [], {}, false, true, NaN];

let empty = []
for (let i in arr) {
  if (arr[i] === "") {
    empty.push(`${i} ("${arr[i]}")`)
  }
}

console.log(empty.join(", "))
```